# Special Values of a L function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, special-functions, l-functions

Suppose $f$ is the following modular forms

\begin{equation}
f=\eta(q^5)^4 [\eta(q)^4+5\,\eta(q)^3\eta(q^{25})+20 \eta(q)^2\eta(q^{25})^2+25\eta(q)\eta(q^{25})^3+25 \eta(q^{25})^4]
\end{equation}

where $\eta$ is the Dedekind's eta function, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\eta(q)=q^{\frac{1}{24}} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)
\end{equation}

$f$ is of weight $4$ and level 25 (with group $\Gamma_0(25)$). I want to find whether the twisted $L$ functions, $L(f,\chi,s)$ vanishes at $s=2$ or not, where $\chi$ is the quadratic character $(./5)$. I tried to show this use modular symbols, but have not made any progress. Anyone got any ideas?

In the note, Overconvergent Modular Symbols by Robert Pollack,

http://math.bu.edu/people/rpollack/Papers/Overconvergent_modular_symbols.pdf

In page 3 there is a formula

\begin{equation}
L(g,\chi,1)=\frac{\tau(\chi)}{N} \sum_{a\, \text{mod}\, N} \bar{\chi}(a)2 \,\pi \,i \int_{i\,\infty}^{-a/N}g(z)dz
\end{equation}

where $g$ is a modular form of weight 1. I am wondering whether there is a formula for weight 4. Then we could transform $L(f,\chi,2)$ into a sum of integrals, which might be helpful.

Comment: If this is an eigenform, there are formulas that are valid for any weight.  Look up Waldspurger's formulas for central L-values.

Comment: There is indeed an integral formula for all modular forms of any weight. Start from the identity $f_\chi = \frac{\tau(\chi)}{m} \cdot \sum_{a \mathrm{mod} m} \overline{\chi}(-a) f(z+a/m)$ (which is just Fourier transform) and integrate $f_\chi(z) z \mathrm{d}z$ from 0 to $i\infty$. Here $\chi$ is a primitive Dirichlet character mod $m$ and $f_\chi = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \chi(n) q^n$.

Comment: Now for your question, the integral $\int_{a/m}^{i\infty} f(z) z \mathrm{d}z$ is an integral over the modular symbol $\{a/m,i\infty\}$. This is a period of $f$ and there are algorithms to compute them, see William Steins's PhD thesis *Explicit approaches to modular abelian varieties*

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you very much for your reply, do you have a reference for this formula?

Comment: This is stated without proof in Manin's article *Parabolic points and zeta functions of modular curves* (see the first formula in the proof of Thm 3.9) http://wstein.org/edu/Fall2003/252/references/Manin-Parabolic/index.html (in this article $f$ has weight 2, but the assertion holds for any weight) This is just the Fourier decomposition of a primitive Dirichlet character, I suggest that you work it out on your own or look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27489/the-discrete-fourier-transform-of-a-dirichlet-charachter

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you again. I have proved it, which is basically manipulation of characters and fourier coefficients. In general, are the integral over the modular symbols evaluated numerically by computer (like in sagemath)?

Comment: @Wenzhe. I know that Magma can do it although its normalization is not clear to me. I'm not sure about Sage. When I had to compute periods I used the standard trick (explained in William Stein's PhD thesis) to reduce to an integral of the form $\int_\alpha^\infty$ where $\alpha$ is in the upper-half plane. It is easy to evaluate this integral numerically because $f$ decays exponentially (by definition).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Sorry for bothering you again and I have a philosophy question. Suppose you use Mathematica to evaluate an integral which decays exponentially, if it is nonzero, say $1.2342134213\pm 2\times10^{-10}$, is it mathematically rigorous that we claim it is non-zero in number theory papers? Theoretically, you could check the code of Mathematica and prove that the error given by it is an upper bound, thus this value is non-zero.

Comment: @Wenzhe. According to my experience it's common in mathematical papers to claim that a number is nonzero if Mathematica's output (or any other software) is visibly nonzero. In the case of integrals or sums which decay exponentially, it's easy to make the argument rigorous by bounding the error term, so people usually don't bother to write it. Of course, proving that a number is zero is another matter, and a computer-based approximation never suffices.

Comment: @Wenzhe: Even though this question is two years old, I just want to point out a reference, equation 8.6 of "On p-adic analouges of conjectures of BSD" by Mazur-Tate-Teitelbaum is the formula you are looking for(this is for any integral weight) . As pointed out earlier, it is just a computation and easily done by oneself.

Answer (score 5):

The $L$-series vanishes at the central point (which I presume is $s = 2$ in the OP's normalization, although I'm not sure).

The reason for this is that $f \otimes \chi_{5}$ has eigenvalue equal to $-1$ under the Fricke involution $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 25 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (according to Magma), and the sign of the functional equation of a weight $k$ newform is $i^{k}$ times the Fricke eigenvalue (by Theorem 7.1 of Iwaniec's Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms).

Comment: Thank you very much, I am a beginner (I am a physicist) on modular forms and I will try to understand your answer!